# AnimatedCircularProgress animation starts when the component renders rather than when the button is clicked. How to detect release of button

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to use the following component: https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-progress. But it seems like the animation begins as soon as the component renders, what I would like to do is only start the animation once the Icon has been pressed and capture is called. I'm trying to emulate the functionality of SnapChat video recording. Additionally, another question would be how to catch the event of when the user releases from the button, i.e to stop the recording.

```js
    capture = () => {
      if (this.state.filming) {
        this.refs.circularProgress.performAnimation(100, 30000);
        this.camera.recordAsync({maxDuration: 30}).then(data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
    }
    
    render() {

            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Camera style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' }} type={this.state.type}
                    ref={ref => {
                      this.camera = ref;
                    }}
                    >

                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingHorizontal: 10, marginBottom: 15, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>

                            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="circle-outline" onPress={() => this.capture()}
                                    style={{ color: 'white', top:10, position: 'absolute', fontSize: 100, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                                ></MaterialCommunityIcons>
                                <AnimatedCircularProgress
                                  ref='circularProgress'
                                  size={120}
                                  width={15}
                                  rotation={0}
                                  fill={this.state.spinValue}
                                  tintColor="red"
                                  style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                                  onAnimationComplete={() => console.log('onAnimationComplete')}
                                >

                                </AnimatedCircularProgress>
                                {!this.state.filming && <MaterialCommunityIcons name="video" style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 36, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} onPress={() => this.setState({filming: !this.state.filming})}/>}
                                {this.state.filming && <MaterialCommunityIcons name="camera" style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 36, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} onPress={() => this.setState({filming: !this.state.filming})}/>}
                            </View>

                        </View>
                    </Camera>
                </View>
            )
    }
```

I hope people are familiar with this library and able to help somehow.

I have tried both the method outlined above and using this with the state set from this animation:

```js
Animated.timing(
                  this.state.spinValue,
              {
                  toValue: 100,
                  duration: 2000,
              }
              ).start();
```

I should also mention that `onAnimationCompletes` is logged almost immediately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try calling this method when you want the animation to start

```
this.refs.circularProgress.performLinearAnimation(100, 2000);
```

and about the release action, try the onPressOut prop to touchableopacity

Comment: Thanks! Yes the onPressOut prop is the correct prop for detecting releases. Unfortunately the issue still persists that it starts the animation when the screen renders rather than when the button is pressed. Shall continue to look into it.